# Show that $\Vert T\Vert = \sup\{\vert \langle Tx, y\rangle\vert : x,y\in E, \,\Vert x\Vert \leq 1, \,\Vert y\Vert \leq 1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following task where I'm blocked:

> Show that if $E$ is an inner product space and $T: E\rightarrow E$ is
>   a bounded linear operator, that is
>
> $$\underset{\Vert x\Vert \leq 1}{\sup} \Vert Tx\Vert  < \infty,\quad x\in E$$
>
> then $$\Vert T\Vert  = \sup\{\vert \langle Tx, y\rangle\vert : x, y\in E,\,
>  \Vert x\Vert \leq 1,\, \Vert y\Vert \leq 1\}.$$

In the problem $\langle, \rangle$ denotes inner product. I'm basically stuck here and I don't know how to proceed. I know that generally the norm of a linear operator is defined as:

$$\Vert T\Vert =\underset{\Vert x\Vert \leq 1}{\sup} \Vert Tx\Vert,\quad x\in E.$$

So I guess I need to show that:

$$\Vert T\Vert =\sup \{\Vert Tx\Vert : x\in E,\, \Vert x\Vert \leq 1\} = \sup\{\vert \langle Tx, y\rangle\vert : x, y\in E,\,
 \Vert x\Vert \leq 1,\, \Vert y\Vert \leq 1\}.$$

Am I in the correct trail? Any hints what I should notice here?

Comment: Read this equality as to inequalities. One inequality follows by Cauchy-Schwarz, the other one taking $y=(\|Tx\|)^{-1}Tx$.